# JavaScript ajax behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, recursion

This is my first question, any suggestions on further questions will be appreciated.

When using the following code to update a table I don't see any updates, however when moving the `TableList = {}` into the success function, the table will update like intended.

Can someone give me an explanation to why I need to move the emptying of the object into the success block?

Answers I've read don't seem to help me understand any better.

```
function GetTableData() {
    TableList = {};

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/info/",
        success: function (result) {

            //Moiving 'TableList = {}' here works fine

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                TableList[i] = result[i];

            }
        }
    });
}

function UpdateTable() {
    GetTableData()
    //Update table cells
    setTimeout(function () {
        UpdateTable();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: try `var TableList = {};` instead - otherwise it's a global, and global variables should be avoided wherever possible

Comment: If `UpdateTable` depends on `TableList` having the correct data in it, it's bad practice to use `setTimeout` as you have, because there is no guarantee the Ajax call will always give you results within a second. (Even if every time you've observed it it has been much quicker than that.) You should just call `UpdateTable()` in the `success` callback, after updating `TableList`, and then you guarantee it will never happen until the data is all there.

Comment: Also, `$.ajax` is **asynchronous** , so updating tables immediately after `GetTableData()` is always going to end up with `TableList` being empty when you try to update from that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.ajax is asynchronous, so the response comes "later"

You call GetTableData() ...

- first thing it does is clear TableList
- second thing it does is begin the asynchronous call
- then it returns
- Your code then updates using the EMPTY TableList (becuase it hasn't been filled yet)
- some time later, TableList is filled
- a second later, repeat the fruitless loop

One solution is this

```
function GetTableData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/info/",
        success: callback
    });
}

function UpdateTable() {
    GetTableData(function(TableList) {
        //Update table cells
        setTimeout(UpdateTable, 1000);
    });
}
```

Now the following happens

- call GetTableData()
- ajax starts
- when data is received, the success function calls the callback with the response as the first argument
- your callback code updates the table cells
- then initiates a timeOut to repeat the whole thing again